# Issue while creating fire base function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Tried creating a firebase function but after deployment i am getting prj url rather than function url,as shown in the firebase link https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

logs:

- functions: Finished running predeploy script.
  i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
- functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
  i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
  i  functions: packaged functions (36.94 KB) for uploading
- functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
  i  functions: creating function makeUppercase...
- functions[makeUppercase]: Successful create operation.
- Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/prjname-faf3a/overview

Comment: Please edit your question to show the output you get when you run `firebase deploy`.

Comment: Frank van Puffelen ,I have added my logs

Comment: In that case it looks like your index.js doesn't contain any HTTP-triggered function. Only those result in a URL being created/assigned. If you do think your index.js *does* contain a function that should result in a URL, please update your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).